# alphabetical sorting is not working in elastic search with haystack

Tags: django, search, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am using elastic search with haystack. My problem is I am not able to sort out results alphabetically. Please note that the content is in greek. Following is my index.

```
class ProfileIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    sorted_title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title', indexed=False, stored=True)
```

I have added sorted_title specifically for sorting.

Here's the index settings:

```
    ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX_SETTINGS = {
    'settings': {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "ngram_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "haystack_ngram_tokenizer",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "greek_lowercase",
                        "greek_stem",
                        "english_stem",
                        "my_stop",
                        "haystack_ngram"
                    ]
                },
                "edgengram_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "greek_lowercase",
                        "greek_stem",
                        "english_stem",
                        "my_stop",
                        "haystack_edgengram"
                    ]
                },
                "myanalyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "greek_lowercase",
                        "greek_stem",
                        "english_stem",
                        "my_stop",
                        "my_edgengram",
                    ]
                },
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "haystack_ngram_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "nGram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 12,
                },
                "haystack_edgengram_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "edgeNGram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 12,
                    "side": "front"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "haystack_ngram": {
                    "type": "nGram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 12
                },
                "haystack_edgengram": {
                    "type": "edgeNGram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 12
                },
                "my_edgengram": {
                    "type": "edgeNGram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 10
                },
                "my_ngram": {
                    "type": "nGram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 10
                },
                "greek_lowercase": {
                    "type": "lowercase",
                    "language": "greek"
                },
                "greek_stem": {
                    "type": "stemmer",
                    "name": "greek"
                },
                "english_stem": {
                    "type": "stemmer",
                    "name": "english"
                },
                "my_stop": {
                    "type": "stop",
                    "stopwords": ["_greek_", "_english_"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If sorted_title is for sorting purpose only, I think that you should index it (mandatory for sorting) and that you should NOT analyze it. (or if you must, you should use a keyword analyzer). Sorting and facetting on analyzed fields can lead to unexpected results, as all the token created by the analyzer are taken into account

Comment: I'm no elasticsearch/haystack expert, but I had a similar problem once, where my custom analyzer settings hadn't been applied. In the end I had success by switching to the 'standard' analyzer with the help of this article: http://wellfireinteractive.com/blog/custom-haystack-elasticsearch-backend/ Sorry if this is completely useless.

Comment: @ptrck thanks for posting link. Yes I have configured as mentioned in article, the problem it I can't use standard analyzer as I am having another requirements too.